# Weird Custom UITableViewCell behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got a really weird problem with a custom UITableViewCell. Btw, i am using an UIViewController. So, i crafted the cell in Storyboard (like in the image bellow) and i set it's class to my custom UITableViewCell class. Then I created all the IBOutlets and IBActions in the custom cell class.
[image]

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    PostTableViewCell *cell = (PostTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [cell setCellContentWithPost:[PostsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

My custom UITableViewCell class:

```
#import "PostTableViewCell.h"    
@implementation PostTableViewCell

- (void)setCellContentWithPost:(SDPost*)post {

    self.alpha = 0.f;
    self.postTitleLabel.text = post.title;

    [self.thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post.thumbnailURL] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageHandleCookies];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
        self.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];

}

-(void)awakeFromNib{

    self.postTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.postTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:16.5];

    self.readingTimeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.33 green:0.74 blue:0.15 alpha:1];
    self.readingTimeView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.readingTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.readingTimeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Bold" size:11.75];

    self.commentsCountView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.74 green:0.19 blue:0.4 alpha:1];
    self.commentsCountView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.commentsCountLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.commentsCountLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Bold" size:11.75];

}
```

I tried to style the cell from the initWithStyle method of the UITableViewCell, but for some reason it never gets called, so i ended up doing this in awakeFromNib.
So, the problem is: I think i am doing something wrong, because as you can see in this GIF (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6crcjbmitr5fmk7/Untitled%20%281%29.gif?m=), the heart button it get's automatically turned on/off as i scroll through the cells.

Can anyone of you guys help me fix this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you updating the datasource PostsArray after you click on the heart?

Comment: Check code in `setCellContentWithPost`. You must be resetting image of `heart button`

Comment: @jithinroy, no, i am just changing the heart button's image.

Comment: you should have a Bool (checked or unchecked) value in PostArray, when user select the heart (checked) or unchecked. here is similar [example Table View Accessory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Unless I missed something, I don't see any code setting the heart image. Is this exactly the code you are executing or did you trim it before posting here?

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis Yes, i trimmed the code that changed the heart image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by checking if the hearth should be filled or not. I stored the post id using NSUserDefaults and in `setCellContentWithPost` i added an if statement that checks if the cell's post is favorited.

Thanks for interest guys!

Comment: Unless you need the filled-state of the heart to persist between launches of your app, you shouldn't use NSUserDefaults for this purpose. Instead, you should create a property (an integer, or array if you want multiple indexPaths to be stored) to store the indexPath.row, and use an if-else clause in cellForRowAtIndexPath to check whether the current indexPath.row is the same (or contained in the array) as the one stored in your property.

Comment: @rdelmar I need it to persist between launches, that's why is saved it with NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the cell is displayed it takes value from your PostsArray array. So when you click on the heart, you should update its corresponding object in the array.

Comment: I don't want to change anything when the heart button is tapped. The issue is that heart image is randomly changing it's status. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: You have to store somewhere that you have tapped the heart button. So that you can use it when UITableView tries to redraw your cell again.

Comment: That's what i have done. Check my answer. Thank you anyways !

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you have the same CellIdentifier for all your cells, which is fine in this case if you are very careful on how you are handling the "heart" element.

1. You should have a way to determine which elements on the cell have been "liked". As I suppose you need to know on which elements your user pressed the heart button.
2. When initialising/reusing your cell you need to be sure that the heart button is set properly to "red/on" or "white/off".

For instance :

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        PostTableViewCell *cell = (PostTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[PostTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        [cell setHeartState:[[AnArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] hasBeenLikedByUser]]


        [cell setCellContentWithPost:[PostsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return cell;
    }
```

It is just a quick draft.

Hope that helps